# Porque cuando uso cin dentro de un for no se pausa?

Tags: c++

Hola he puesto un cin dentro de un for para que me vaya pidiendo información pero cuando lo hago me lo hace todo de golpe ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando deberia pedir uno por uno.
Parte del codigo:

```
int entradas,t;
    cout << "Introduce el numero de entradas:";
    cin >>entradas;
    int ar[entradas];
    for(t=0;t<entradas;t++)
        cout << "Introduce un numero: ";
        cin >> numero;
```

Alguien sabe porque hace esos saltos no puedo ingresar varios numeros??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(t=0;t<entradas;t++)
  cout << "Introduce un numero: ";
  cin >> numero;
```

Como el `for` ocupa más de una instrucción tienes que encerrar el código entre llaves

```
for(t=0;t<entradas;t++)
{
  cout << "Introduce un numero: ";
  cin >> numero;
}
```

Comment: que despiste por mi parte gracias eferion!

Comment: @OmarOmar son cosas que pasan

Comment: También puede ser que no libere el buffer de entrada, además de las llaves, no?

Comment: @Jogofus que buffer tiene que liberar? No es un fichero que haya abierto sino la entrada estándar

Comment: Pero cuando lees datos de entrada por parte del usuario, no se queda en buffer el "\n"?

Comment: @Jogofus eso solo te afecta si llamas a `getline` o similares... las lecturas de este ejemplo descartan el salto de linea

Comment: @eferion gracias por la respuesta. Siempre había pensado que el que obviaba el salto de línea era getline(cin, variable). De hecho, alguna vez he usado cin y en la segunda variable me ha guardado el salto de línea